# At what level should I implement communication between nodes on a distributed system?

Tags: distributed

I'm building a web application that from day one will be on the limits of what a single server can handle. So I'm considering to adopt a distributed architecture with several identical nodes. The goal is to provide scalability (add servers to accommodate more users) and fault tolerance. The nodes need to share *some* state between them, therefore some communication between them is required. I believe I have the following alternatives to implement this communication in Java:

- Implement it using sockets and a custom protocol.
- Use RMI
- Use web services (each node can send and receive/parse HTTP request).
- Use JMS
- Use another high-level framework like [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org) or [hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)

I would like to know how this technologies compare to each other:

- When the number of nodes increases
- When the amount of communication between the nodes increases (1000s of messages per second and/or messages up to 100KB etc)
- On a practical level (eg ease of implementation, available documentation, license issues etc)
- I'm also interested to know what technologies are people using in real production projects (as opposed to experimental or academic ones).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [Jini](http://www.jini.org/wiki/What_is_Jini%3F).

It gives you automatic service discovery, service leasing, and downloadable proxies so that the actual client/server communication protocol is up to you and not enforced by the framework (e.g. you can choose HTTP/RMI/whatever).

The framework is built around acknowledgement of the [8 Fallacies of Distributed Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing) and [recovery-oriented computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery-oriented_computing). i.e. you *will* have network problems, and the architecture is built to help you recover and maintain a service.

If you also use [Javaspaces](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/JavaSpaces/) it's trivial to implement workflows and consumer-producer architectures. Producers will write into the Javaspaces, and one or more consumers will take that work from the space (under a transaction) and work with it. So you scale it simply by providing more consumers.